# Can't find ogg with PkgConfig

Tags: cmake, ogg, gentoo, pkg-config

I'm trying to build secondlife viewer but fail on:

```
Building 'Second Life Test' Version 3.8.5.34241
-- Found PkgConfig: /usr/bin/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-pkg-config (found version "0.29") 
-- checking for module 'ogg'
--   package 'ogg' not found
```

- I've libogg installed: https://bpaste.net/show/c6d60173da44
- full build log: https://bpaste.net/show/9b3ecbd254c4
- pkg_check_modules soruce: https://bitbucket.org/lindenlab/viewer-release/src/dfd2e1723b72b62e8b6c3746fd5f7fbb1132f389/indra/cmake/Audio.cmake?at=default&fileviewer=file-view-default

full build log shows that I'm using `USESYSTEMLIBS` flag, that means that `pkg_check_modules(OGG REQUIRED ogg)` just doesn't find `/usr/lib64/pkgconfig/ogg.pc` with some reason...

What could cause such mysterious bug?

(here is CMakeOut log : https://bpaste.net/show/a2fc804afc73)

`pkg-config --exists ogg --print-errors` returns nothing

Comment: In the build log `Using PKG_CONFIG_LIBDIR=...` means that someone redefines default search path for pkg-config. And this variable doesn't contain `/usr/lib64/pkgconfig`. That's why `ogg` is not found at configuration stage.

Comment: @Tsyvarev thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

seems like just CMake doesn't work right -__-' https://github.com/Techwolf/techwolf-overlay/issues/2#issuecomment-144851500

> This bug is in cmake 3.3.x, downgrade to 3.2.3-r1 will fix it

everything works with 3.2.3

```
-- checking for module 'ogg'
--   found ogg, version 1.3.2
```

Comment: Would be nice to get the CMake mantis bug tracker number. If the bug is not known upstream, please do so. Otherwise there is no chance to get it fixed.